# Removing application access to user from User interface by using Microsoft graph API or Azure AD graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I created admin console in the User interface where admin can perform all the operations such create, delete the user, assign applications to user and remove application access to users from the user interface

I tired to remove application access to the users from the User Interface by using Microsoft graph API and Azure AD graph api
i used following azure AD graph api

https://graph.windows.net/tenantid/users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments/{appId}?api-version=1.6

but it is showing the error when i tested in the postman "Invalid resource identifier for EntitlementGrant."

Idont know what to do can anyone help me about these error and how to resolve these problem.

Answer (score 4):

You may be getting this error because you are trying to delete the application access using AppId of the application. Please make sure to use "AssignmentID" from Azure Portal  which is unique ID of the specific role assignment and links the user/group and the service principal object. 
Go to Azure Active Directory > Users > Select specific User > Applications > Select any application to navigate to "Assignment Details" blade.

See screenshot below -

[image]

This unique id is also available as "ObjectID" if querying application role assignments through Graph API -

```
https://graph.windows.net/{TenantID}/users/{UserID}/appRoleAssignments
```

Here is the sample output of the above API call.

```
"odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/sasharms.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment",
"value": [
    {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment",
        "objectType": "AppRoleAssignment",
        "objectId": "r7rDMrnDo0uCuwnosRwwzuziiF5B8s9FnsotYya5DMU",
        "deletionTimestamp": null,
        "creationTimestamp": "2018-05-10T14:10:49.8197813Z",
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "principalDisplayName": "SaurabhSharma",
        "principalId": "32c3baaf-c3b9-4ba3-82bb-09e8b11c30ce",
        "principalType": "User",
        "resourceDisplayName": "WebAppOpenIdGraphApi",
        "resourceId": "90658e39-2559-48fb-a27a-5e50cca94288"
    }
```

This Id is ideally used for performing various operations against the application using any programmatic interfaces like PowerShell and Graph APIs.