# Microsoft Graph API - Get Assignment ID of Service Principal from User

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am wondering how to retrieve the Assignment ID of a service principal assigned to an user.
I found this post on Stackoverflow where the Assignment ID is retrieved by URL, but I want to retrieve it via Graph API in C#: [Removing application access to user from User interface by using Microsoft graph API or Azure AD graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237947/removing-application-access-to-user-from-user-interface-by-using-microsoft-graph)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an *app role assignment*.
You can list them through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http (`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo`).

The endpoint will list application permissions granted to other applications as well as user roles, since both are app roles in Azure AD.
To call it you do need to know the object ID of your service principal/enterprise application.
If needed, you can query for it from the service principal list endpoint using e.g. the application/client ID.

Then you can delete one through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-delete-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http (`DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{resource-SP-id}/appRoleAssignedTo/{appRoleAssignment-id}`).

Also, if it is more convenient in your case, you can query for a user's app role assignments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, and delete them through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.